# Java Space Invaders Game Rapid Fire Cheat Triggering Game Win too Early

Tags: java, space

So I am new the very new programmer modifying/adding things to a already made space invaders game to get more familiar with how games are programmed. I am trying to add cheats to the game and the rapid fire cheat is giving me some trouble. When you choose rapid fire and go through the level, the game can sometimes trigger the notifyWin early with some aliens still left. This is because sometimes 2 shots hit the same enemy at the exact same time making the computer think that 2 different enemies are being killed, thus leaving a few aliens sometimes left over while the "You have won!" screen pops up. The win is triggered when the alien count reaches 0 shooting the same enemy twice reduces the alien count by 2 instead of 1. I can't for the life of me seem to figure this out.

```
// reduce the alient count, if there are none left, the player has won
    alienCount--;

if (alienCount == 0)
    {
        notifyWin ();
    }
```

Here is the code where the shot collides with the enemy

```
/**
     * Notification that this shot has collided with another
     * entity
     * 
     * @parma other The other entity with which we've collided
     */
    public void collidedWith(Entity other) {
            // prevents double kills, if we've already hit something,
            // don't collide
            if (used) {
                    return;
            }

            // if we've hit an alien, kill it!
            if (other instanceof AlienEntity) {
                    // remove the affected entities
                    game.removeEntity(this);
                    game.removeEntity(other);

                    // notify the game that the alien has been killed
                    game.notifyAlienKilled();
                    used = true;
            }
    }
```

Comment: I think it would help to see the code where the shot collides with the enemy. The double counting of enemies being killed is what you mentioned as being the problem.

Comment: @MC10 I added the code where the shot collides

Comment: I would ask for the code that calls collidedWith but that would be too much trouble. I made a simple game like this before and I did what @hack_on mentioned in the answers. Just saw his edit, that should be fine too.

Comment: Are you using multiple threads? eg an event listener thread separate from the main thread?

Answer (score 2):

One possible solution is to add the enemies as objects to a list.  When they have been shot, remove them from the list, checking that they are still there before hand.  Do a notifyWin when the list is empty.  This way, if the logic doing the collision detection on the enemies generates too many hits, it will still work correctly.

The chances are good that this list exists already in order to render the enemies on the screen.

**EDIT**: now that I see the method, you could probably just do the following at the top of collidedWith:

```
if (used || !game.containsEntity(other)) {
    return;
}
```

Where the method containsEntity checks for the existence of the entity in the internal list or structures that hold the game actors (entities).

Comment: The only time containsEntity is an error is inside collidedWith, the two other methods in the ShotEntity class don't treat this as an error

Comment: I was assuming that you would write containsEntity yourself.  Perhaps you will need to write a different method containsEnemy on the game that will take an "enemy" type class and check if it is in whatever structure "removeEntity" removes it from.

Comment: the removeEntity method in the Game class just adds the entity to removeList which is an Array and then removeList later clears

Comment: I can't help without the code.  I suggest either write a new method that checks for enemies, re-write containsEntity to get rid of the error, or if you can't work those out ask a new question with just the relevant code to the new problem.